# Are there any academic data sets that force users to release any source code written to analyse them?

Tags: data, open-science, license

I am curious to know whether there exists any data set that forces users to publicly release any source code written to analyse it.

Comment: I'm not sure that such a restriction would even be legally enforceable.

Comment: @aeismail I am not sure either but I would tend to think that if a contract has to be signed to access the data set then one might add a clause to force users to release the code.

Comment: I am wondering if analyzing data to produce aggregate results would count as a "remix" for creative commons licenses.

Comment: @aeismail, if the dataset is only available under contract from the owner, then lots of things like this would probably be enforceable (cite the originator, publish the analysis code, etc.). I know of no data set that does this, but there's plenty of academic software whose licenses require citation of the authors.

Comment: So the owner of a proprietary data set would demand that software used to analyze it be open-source? Talk about hypocrisy!

Comment: @aeismail Can you define proprietary data? (The definition is a bit fuzzy to me)

Comment: @aeismail Why would it have to be proprietary data? What's stopping anyone from releasing a dataset under an open license that also enforces you to share code? Maybe in practice it's not feasible, but I don't see why you couldn't.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Proprietary just means it's owned by somebody who is controlling access to it.

Comment: @RogerFan: Because there's always the possibility that you could use commercial tools to analyze it, and therefore you can't adhere to or enforce such a provision.

Comment: @aeismail Sure, but that just means that you can't use commercial tools to analyze it. That's a limitation the license imposes, but it doesn't mean the license is impossible or unenforceable.

Comment: @aeismail Thanks. A lot of data sets in the medical field can only be accessed through a contract typically asking researchers to respect patients' privacy, medical researchers are typically fine with it even though it means the data set is proprietary. Otherwise, it may be possible as Roger indicates to add some provision in the data set license without requiring users to sign anything, so as to avoid making the data set proprietary.

Comment: @aeismail As for the use of commercial tools to analyze, it might be made possible by defining "source code written to analyse it" as code written specifically to analyze the data set, not general toolkit like Matlab.  I agree that what I am saying is vague, that's why I was looking for such data sets to see how it was handled :)

Comment: @aeismail, of course it's hypocritical, but you didn't ask about that, you asked about enforceability. I know of no datasets that do this, but that doesn't mean that someone couldn't try.

Answer (score 4):

Open data licenses apparently do exist, for instance, Open Data Commons maintains the [ODbL](http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/summary/). I don't think that this has a restriction on code used for *analysis*, but it does put a share-alike restriction on any derivative datasets.

> If you publicly use any adapted version of this database, or works produced from an adapted database, you must also offer that adapted database under the ODbL.

This essentially ensures that the derived database (or steps used to create it) used for analysis must be shared, though not necessarily the analysis itself.

I imagine that you could modify this license to mandate that you share the steps used to create any work produced (i.e. the analysis code) as well under some kind of open license, but I am not a lawyer, and I did not find an existing license that does this in my (short) search. In particular, this could easily be troublesome if you use closed-source third-party software in your analysis (e.g. Stata, Matlab), though people have overcome similar issues with GPL licenses.

Answer (score 1):

The data user agreement for this dataset (MIMIC/eICU) requires users to share their code. https://physionet.org/pnw/a/manage-duas :

> If I openly disseminate my results, I will also contribute the code used to produce those results to a defined PhysioNet repository (physionet.org/physiotools/repository/) that is open to the research community.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would work in the US, where facts [cannot](http://www.newmediarights.org/business_models/artist/what_can%E2%80%99t_be_copyrighted) [be](http://www.cendi.gov/publications/04-8copyright.html#214) [copyrighted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications,_Inc.,_v._Rural_Telephone_Service_Co.), so -- once you publicly publish data -- there's nothing stopping anybody else from republishing it in a different form. That might be [plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism), but you can usually get around that by citing the source of your data.

Comment: Facts can not be copyrighted but _a collection of facts_ can be, and if they can show that you mined their database they can indeed sue and win. (Common practice is to selectively add a few deliberately erroneous data points in a place where they don't cause trouble, to act as. A "smoking gun" to demonstrate the copyright violation)

Comment: US federal law says trap streets are not copyrightable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_street#Legal_issues) and that facts stolen from other sources don't by themselves create copyright violations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Pursuit#Fred_Worth_lawsuit). However, obtaining facts in certain ways *might* be illegal, including data mining another database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues

Comment: US law continues to evolve in this area. Understand copyright, and understand that a license agreement is a contract.

Comment: @keshlam A collection of facts cannot be copyrighted in the US. The *selection and arrangement* of those facts can be, but only if there is at least a bare minimum amount of creativity in selecting and arranging those facts.

Comment: Also, the dataset does not have to be public. Many datasets are available by application. It could be a contractual condition of being given access to the data is that you have to share the code used to analyse it.